# iOS8 CoreMotion get updates from startActivityUpdatesToQueue when the app is suspended

Tags: ios, core-motion

[The handler block is executed on a best effort basis and updates are not delivered while your app is suspended.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionActivityManager_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionActivityManager/startActivityUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:)

the Doc says that the handler block will not be delivered when the app is suspended.But what I want to do is to get user motion activity background and give user a local notification at some time.Any other solutions or which background mode should help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use location updates background mode to keep your application alive in background.

- Add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in your plist file.
- In Capabilities enable `Background Modes` and inside that enable `Location Updates`
- Add a location manager and always keep it running

NOTE: This can get your app rejected by apple so make sure you also have some use of location updates in your app.